# What is the Turing degree of the set of true formula of Second Order Arithmetic?

Tags: logic, ordinals, foundations, reverse-math

The set of true formula of First Order Arithmetic is not arithmetical (by Tarski's undefinability theorem) and it has Turing degree $\emptyset^{(\omega)}$.

What about the set of true formula of Second Order Arithmetic?
I assume we can apply Tarski's undefinability theorem again and saying that this the set is not analytical.
What is the Turing degree of this set?

More in general what is the Turing degree of the set of true formula of $n$-order Arithmetic?
Is there a rule which defines a function which maps the order of the Arithmetic to the ordinal of the Turing degree of the corresponding set of the true formula of that Arithmetic?

Answer (score 4):

*I'll focus only on the second-order situation here, since my answer applies a fortiori to the higher orders.*

It essentially$^1$ requires us to introduce a new notation, to the point that - in my opinion - true second-order arithmetic (which I'll call "$TA_2$") is fundamentally impossible to describe in a concrete way.

I think it will help to start by considering a simpler example, namely the set of true $\Pi^1_1$ sentences of arithmetic. Up to Turing degree this is just the set of indices of computable well-orderings. We know how to make sense of ${\bf 0^{(\alpha)}}$ for a computable ordinal $\alpha$, but this only gets us hyperarithmetic sets. So we introduce a new idea, the *hyperjump*, which solves the problem tautologically: this is the map $X\mapsto$ [$\mathcal{O}^X$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperarithmetical_theory#Relativized_hyperarithmeticity_and_hyperdegrees). The $\Pi^1_1$ theory of arithmetic is then just $\mathcal{O}^\emptyset$, or $\mathcal{O}$.

(I'm being a bit sloppy here, and in particular ignoring the distinction between computable well-orderings and *notations*; this is a bit technical and doesn't affect the Turing degree involved.)

One level higher, we hit the set of true $\Pi^1_2$ sentences (or thinking structurally, the set of indices for computable examples of a more complicated type of object called a **dilator**). One might reasonably expect (in analogy with the arithmetic case, and the usual Turing jump) that this is just $\mathcal{O}^\mathcal{O}$. However, this is much, much, much, ... , much more complicated than anything you can get by iterating the hyperjump a "reasonable" number of times, in the same way that $\mathcal{O}$ itself is more complicated than anything you can get by applying the usual Turing jump a "reasonable" number of times (the latter being the hyperarithmetic sets).

And this happens at *each* subsequent level: the "$\Pi^1_k$-jump" is liliputian compared to the "$\Pi^1_{k+1}$-jump." One would really have to introduce new symbols for each of these. (Incidentally, on the "structural" side the generalization of ordinals and dilators is **ptykes**, introduced by Girard).

Of course, this isn't really the end of the story. Even granting the above we can still try to understand $TA_2$ by comparing it to structures/sets we find more concrete. For example, the *first-order* theory of the partial order of Turing degrees (and some other degree structures) is $1$-equivalent to $TA_2$. Meanwhile, many of the important reals we get from large cardinals are strictly less complicated than $TA_2$ if they exist in the first place (e.g. $0^{\sharp}$ is $\Delta^1_3$). But I think these observations really go the other way: e.g. "$Th_{FOL}(\mathcal{D})$ computes $TA_2$" doesn't concretify $TA_2$, it reveals that $\mathcal{D}$ is really mysterious.

---

$^1$That's not *quite* true, but I'd say it's still pretty morally correct. Here are two amendations:

- If $V=L$, we can talk about iterating the Turing jump past $\omega_1^{CK}$ via [mastercodes](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.jsl/1183740554). Roughly speaking, in the mastercode hierarchy the true theory of second-order arithmetic will appear at level $\alpha$, where $\alpha$ is the lowest level of the $L$-hierarchy whose set of reals satisfies that theory. But this only works assuming $V=L$ (or similar) and is also fairly tautological; moreover, the mastercode hierarchy has some annoying pathologies. So while interesting, this isn't really satisfying.
- At the other end of the set-theoretic spectrum and considering first a "higher-type" analogue of this problem, it turns out that reasonably-strong large cardinal hypotheses imply that "natural" operations on Turing degrees are (pre-)well-ordered in a particular way. The relevant term here is "Martin's Conjecture" (MC). While the full MC is still open, much partial progress is known, and in particular Steel's proof of one half of its weaker version the relevant part of MC for *uniformly representable* functions is applicable to our situation: the relevant function $$TSOA: r\mapsto Th_{SOL}(\mathbb{N},\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}),+,\cdot,\in,r)$$ lives in a particularly natural pre-well-ordering. It therefore has a naturally-associated ordinal, namely its **rank** $\sigma$ in this pre-well-ordering. Getting back to the original question, one might hope that "the second-order theory of $\mathbb{N}$ has degree ${\bf 0^{(\sigma)}}$" is true in some sense, but I actually don't know a precise interpretation of this. Ultimately I think that this kind of analysis-by-ordinals is not really addressing the concrete question of the OP although it is quite interesting.

Comment: What is the Turing degree of  Kleene's ${\mathcal {O}}$?

Comment: Can you also explain me whats is  ${\mathcal {D}}$

Comment: @holmes The symbol "$\mathcal{O}$" is used interchangeably for the set and its Turing degree; the whole point of that part of my answer is that there isn't really a better description of $\mathcal{O}$'s Turing degree than "$\mathcal{O}$'s Turing degree."

Comment: @holmes Meanwhile, $\mathcal{D}$ is the partial order of Turing degees, and $Th_{FOL}(\mathcal{D})$ is its first-order theory. The full first-order theory of the Turing degrees is Turing equivalent (and much more) to the full second-order theory of arithmetic.

Comment: So for no ordinal $\alpha$  you can reach  $ {\mathcal {O}}$ from the degree of the halting problem with $\alpha$ numbers of Turing jumps

Comment: @holmes Well, that's not quite true. The issue is that (as I said) "iterate the jump $\alpha$-many times" is only unambiguous if $\alpha$ is a computable ordinal - and that only gets us the hyperarithmetic sets. We can say that $\mathcal{O}={\bf 0}^{(\omega_1^{CK})}$ in a sense via mastercodes, but that sense arguably requires us to already have $\mathcal{O}$ in hand (so that we can get an appropriately-canonical well-ordering of type $\omega_1^{CK}$). And we don't necessarily have anything like the "mastercode fix" once we climb much higher (we do if $V=L$, but ...).

Comment: Can we conclude by saying  that the set of true formula of arbitrary order arithmetic ( expressed by any ordinal)  has a Turing degree, but already for second order arithmetic this degree is much further beyond the horizon of present mathematics (in terms of Truing degrees theory and ordinal theory), even more this is true also for subsets of  second order arithmetic like  $\Pi_3^1$  arithmetic.

Comment: Maybe one thing that is possible to conjecture is that the proof theoretic ordinal of $n$-order arithmetic is bigger than the ordinal of the Turing degree of the true formula, like in the case of first order arithmetic  the first is $\epsilon_0$  and the second is  $\omega$

Comment: The dead link to the paper on mastercodes used to go to this paper: Harold T. Hodes, *[Jumping Through the Transfinite: The Master Code Hierarchy of Turing Degrees](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=hodes+jumping+through+transfinite),* The Journal of Symbolic Logic, Vol. 45, No. 2 (Jun., 1980), pp. 204-220; [DOI: 10.2307/2273183](https://doi.org/10.2307/2273183), [JSTOR](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2273183)